# How can i get startX and startY position?

Tags: silverlight

How can i get the startX and startY position of the `rectToGetXAndY`. This piece of functionality is very critical to my application but it is driving me crazy. The only approach that comes to my mind is to ask the user to manually click on the top left border of the grid and then handle mouseleftbuttondown event. Obviously this is not the solution i want. Here is my code :-

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="DelSilverlightApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="DarkSlateGray">
        <Grid x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" Background="HotPink" Width="300" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT :-**

This the code behind :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DelSilverlightApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GeneralTransform gt = rectToGetXAndY.TransformToVisual(null);
            Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            MessageBox.Show(p.X + " " + p.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work using @AnthonyWJones' code using the following:

XAML

```
        <UserControl x:Class="GetPositionUi.MainPage"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="DarkSlateGray">
                <Grid x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" 
                        Background="HotPink" 
                        Width="300" 
                        Height="300" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PositionTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=ReferencePosition}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace GetPositionUi
    {
        public partial class MainPage : UserControl
        {

            #region ReferencePosition

            /// <summary>
            /// ReferencePosition Dependency Property
            /// </summary>
            public static readonly DependencyProperty ReferencePositionProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("ReferencePosition", typeof(Point), typeof(MainPage),
                    new PropertyMetadata((Point)(new Point(0, 0)),
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnReferencePositionChanged)));

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the ReferencePosition property.  This dependency property 
            /// indicates the reference position of the child element.
            /// </summary>
            public Point ReferencePosition
            {
                get { return (Point)GetValue(ReferencePositionProperty); }
                set { SetValue(ReferencePositionProperty, value); }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Handles changes to the ReferencePosition property.
            /// </summary>
            private static void OnReferencePositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                ((MainPage)d).OnReferencePositionChanged(e);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Provides derived classes an opportunity to handle changes to the ReferencePosition property.
            /// </summary>
            protected virtual void OnReferencePositionChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
            }

            #endregion

            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
            {
                var arrangedSize = base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
                GeneralTransform gt = rectToGetXAndY.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
                Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                ReferencePosition = p;
                return arrangedSize;
            }
        }
    }
```

The key here is letting the base arrange the controls first, then use the transform to find the position and finally returning the new arrangedSize.

I would not recommend showing a message box at this point, but you can use the dependency property changed callback to do anything you want with the updated position.

Comment: Thanks @Murven but can you tell me what is this TransformToVisual and Transform do? The MSDN explanation doesn't relate to the problem i am trying to solve in any way. Can you tell me what is this actually doing in plain language?

Comment: What this is doing is a matrix transformation between the two different spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) In the specific case you need it is just a translation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix) but it could be any other transformation.

Answer (score 2):

In Silveright you can use this code to determine the current X and Y position of `rectToGetXAndY` relative to `LayoutRoot`:-

```
GeneralTransform gt = rectToGetXAndY.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: @AnthonyWJones :- Your code is returning 0,0 when i show point's X and Y in message box. I want the X and Y position of the inner grid. The starting X and Y position i.e the topmost-leftmost point of the inner grid. One another approach that comes to my mind is to put it in Canvas and then set the absolute position of inner grid and then do innerGrid.GetValue(Canvas.Top) but Grid is better solution for me. Is is possible in Grid?

Comment: @Ankit If you want it relative to the root visual, swap out LayoutRoot for Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement

Comment: @Aaron :- The code itself is not working. No matter whatever visual i give. Neither LayoutRoot nor Application.Current.RootVisual. All i get in my messagebox is 0,0

Comment: @Ankit:  Thats true you get 0,0 because LayoutRoot itself is centered with in the user control.  If you you want it relative to the root visual just pass `null` to `TransformToVisual`.  I wouldn't switch to using a Canvas unless you actually intend to move items to absolute positions yourself.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones : And i still get 0,0! And right! even i don't want to switch to canvas.

Comment: @Ankit:  At what point is your code running, I don't think it works in the constructor, needs to run during or after the loaded event. Also you Usercontrol __is__ the root visual?

Comment: Yes it is UserControl and yes it is the root visual. It's the default MainPage that you get from VisualStudio and yes i have it in Loaded event. Posting code behind in 1 min.

Comment: I just did a test using the following code and it worked:         protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            GeneralTransform gt = rectToGetXAndY.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
            Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        }

Comment: Doing this operation in the ArrangeOverride method will make sure you always have the most up-to-date value, even if the elements are resized or re-positioned.

Comment: @Murven :- Can you please point more details regarding this? Where should i put this overridden method? In MainPage.xaml.cs? And what size should i pass in this method?

Comment: Just copy paste the method in MainPage.xaml.cs. You do not need to run the method, Silverlight will run it for you.

Comment: @Murven :- And what code do i need to write in my mainpage_loaded? Can you please tell? to show the position of inner grid in message box?

Comment: @Ankit: Before doing some other strange stuff (like overidding `ArrangeOverride`) its important to understand why your results differ from mine. I'm using Silverligh 4 could that be a cause? I'm use the default test page generated in the companion web application. My browser client window area is larger than 300x300 (if yours is smaller then you would get the result you are seeing).

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I am getting the exact same results as @Ankit when I do my test using "Loaded": the position result is 0,0. The approach of overriding ArrangeOverride does not work either as it will always report the old position. I am still looking into a way to get the most up-to-date position.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones : You are really funny :d. Why would i ever develop silverlight applications in screen less than 300 px? More than 600px are eaten up by Visual Studio's Properties window and controls window. Do you `really` think anybody would use screen less than 300 px for silverlight application development :D? And interesting thing is the code doesn't work in Mainpage_Loaded but if i put it on some button click it works fine. But, how is it possible? Loaded event only fires after everything has completed loading in memory. Can you throw some light on this? And yes i am using VS2010 SL4

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Also if possible please explain what is this code exactly doing? What is TransformToVisual and Transform doing? I looked for msdn but didn't find the explanation that could relate to my problem in any way. Thanks!

Comment: @Ankit:  Your screen may be more than 300px but the client area of your browser at start up may not be.  Good diagnositics makes __no__ assumptions, on the contrary good diagnositics considers all possibilities no matter "funny" they might seem and specifically eliminates them.  After some test I can see that I can also generate the 0,0 result __sometimes__.  It would appear that even at the  Loaded event this approach not reliable.   There appears to no event that you can use to get a single final value.  Using ArrangeOverride is an option if you must be informed of changes straight away.

Comment: @Ankit, When "Loaded" runs everything is in memory, but the arrangement of the UI has not finished yet, that is why I am using "ArrangeOverride" instead, to make sure that the controls have already been arranged. @AnthonyWJones never suggested you had a 300px monitor, he was referring to the window size of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getoffset.aspx)...

```
Vector vector = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(rectToGetXAndY);
Point currentPoint = new Point(vector.X, vector.Y);
```

Comment: Is it not available in Silverlight? I want solution in Silverlight. VisualTreeHelper has no method called GetOffset. I am sorry my mistake. I will change the post keywords rightway.